# Как правильно сконфигурировать url`ы и структурировать приложения в проекте django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-urls

Пишу некоторое приложение с материалами (это статьи или новости) с системой голосования и комментирования.

Статье/новости можно поставить плюс или/и минус (да, можно и то и другое поставить, но это здесь не важно)
Статью/новость можно комментировать
Комментарию также можно поставить плюс и/или минус

**Вопрос: как правильно сделать маршрутизацию, какие url ы и методы должны быть**
Может комментарии (модель Comment) лучше вынести в отдельное приложение?
Например, мне кажется, что url 'comments//add_plus/' какой-то не правильный. Может модель Comment лучше вынести в отдельное приложение и там уже настраивать свои url`ы?

materials/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

ARTICLE = 'article'
NEWS = 'news'
MATERIALS = (
    ('article', ARTICLE),
    ('news', NEWS),
)

class Material(models.Model):
    _type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=MATERIALS, null=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_publication = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pluses = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    minuses = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Type: {} | Title: {} | Author: {}'.format(self._type, self.title, self.author)

class Comment(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    material = models.ForeignKey(Material, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pluses = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    minuses = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Article: {} | Author: {}'.format(self.material, self.author)
```

materials/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView

from .models import Material, Comment


class IndexView(ListView):
    template_name = 'materials/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'materials'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Material.objects.all()

class MaterialDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Material
    template_name = 'materials/detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print()
        context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(material=self.object)
        return context

def add_plus(request, material_id):
    material = get_object_or_404(Material, pk=material_id)
    material.pluses += 1
    material.save()

    return redirect('/materials/{}/'.format(material_id))
    # return HttpResponseRedirect('materials:detail', args=(material_id))

def add_minus(request, material_id):
    material = get_object_or_404(Material, pk=material_id)
    material.minuses += 1
    material.save()

    # return redirect('/articles/{}/'.format(article_id))
    return redirect('/materials/{}/'.format(material_id))
    # return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('materials:detail', args=(material.id)))

def create_comment(request, material_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        author = request.POST.get('comment-author')
        text = request.POST.get('comment-text')

        material = get_object_or_404(Material, pk=material_id)
        new_comment = Comment.objects.create(material=material, author=author, text=text)
        new_comment.save()
    return redirect('/materials/{}/'.format(material_id))

def comment_add_plus(request, comment_id):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=comment_id)
    comment.pluses += 1
    comment.save()
    material_id = comment.material.pk
    return redirect('/materials/{}/'.format(material_id))

def comment_add_minus(request, comment_id):
    comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, pk=comment_id)
    comment.minuses += 1
    comment.save()
    material_id = comment.material.pk
    return redirect('/materials/{}/'.format(material_id))
```

materials/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import IndexView, MaterialDetailView, add_plus, add_minus, create_comment, comment_add_plus, comment_add_minus

app_name = 'materials'
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
        path('<int:pk>/', MaterialDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
        path('<int:material_id>/add_plus/', add_plus, name='add_plus'),
        path('<int:material_id>/add_minus/', add_minus, name='add_minus'),
        path('<int:material_id>/create_comment/', create_comment, name='create_comment'),
        path('comments/<int:comment_id>/add_plus/', comment_add_plus, name='comment_add_plus'),
        path('comments/<int:comment_id>/add_minus/', comment_add_minus, name='comment_add_minus'),
    ]
```

Comment: не думаю что стоит выносить комментарии отдельным приложением.
а плюсы и минусы можно обрабатывать при помощи ajax и тогда не будет проблем с такими url 'comments//add_plus/' не будет

Comment: @user355827 спасибо за ответ. Да, о ajax тоже думал, именно про лайки.

Comment: ну и еще slug  можете почитать и юзать, для более понятных url

Comment: вот если дальше развивать проект, то можно в отдельное приложение вынести например поиск по сайту. Ну это если солидный поиск делать